# Break up a form with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, fieldset

I have a form, which I want to iterate through. I want to show one fieldset at a time, and then show a "next" and "back" button to go to the next section.

I'm assuming that I start with `$('fieldset');` but how do I access individual elements thereafter? 
`$("fieldset")[i]` does not seem to work.

How would I accomplish that with jQuery?

Comment: `$($('.fieldset')[i]).css(...)`  (Maybe.  I'm new to JQuery)

Comment: @jjnguy - It works. Post as an answer. Bonus if you explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't necessarily recommend this, but:

```
$($('.fieldset')[i]).css(...)
```

Should work.

If you wrap each call to `$('.fieldset')[i]` in a new JQuery selector, you create a new JQuery object out of that single item.  JQuery objects have the method `css` that you want.  Regular dom objects do not. (That's what you get with `$('.fieldset')[i]`)

Answer (score 1):

From [the jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_pull_a_native_DOM_element_from_a_jQuery_object.3F):

> **How do I pull a native DOM element from a jQuery object?**
>
> A jQuery object is an array-like
>   wrapper around one or more DOM
>   elements. To get a reference to the
>   actual DOM elements (instead of the
>   jQuery object), you have two options.
>   The first (and fastest) method is to
>   use array notation:
>
> $('#foo')[0]; // equivalent to
>   document.getElementById('foo') The
>   second method is to use the get
>   function:
>
> $('#foo').get(0); // identical to
>   above, only slower You can also call
>   get without any arguments to retrieve
>   a true array of DOM elements.

To get a jQuery wrapper *back* around the DOM element you just extracted, rewrap it like so:

```
$( $('#foo')[0] ) //now it's ajQuery element again.
```

Comment: @jjnguy ~ Yes, it was also the answer I gave him in chat. I also know the reason _why_ it works ;)

Comment: @drach, I literally wrote my first line of JQuery on Friday last week.  So this was kind of a guess from me.  Glad I was right.

Comment: @drachenstern - You left out the outer `$(...)` wrapper in chat, probably assuming I would know to put that in.

Comment: @Moshe No I didn't  :P : http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/526058#526058

Answer (score 0):

```
$("fieldset").each(function() {
  // code, applied for each fieldset
})
```

Comment: I want to show one at a time. How would I do this using the `display` css property and your code?